# ActivityCompat.requestPermission not showing dialog when called inside onMenuItemClick

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Hi i´m calling ActivityCompat.requestPermission inside my onMenuItemClick to grant the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission . However , ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is not executed .

My target is API 23

I have defined in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

and here is my code which i call inside the onMenuItemClick

```
                case R.id.id_captura:
                     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ChatActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    } else {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ChatActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ChatActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CTE
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    break;
```

And here is my onRequestPermissionsResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CTE: {
             if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Permissions").setMessage("Permissions not granted ").setPositiveButton("Accept", null);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

Aditionally I defined

```
private final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CTE = 1;
```

Comment: any chance youve ever clicked dont ask again on the dialog : 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the  `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` since i´m targeting api 23 , the permissions are requested in runtime but must be also declared in the manifest file .
Deleting that line did the job.